# How to delete nan in a column if conditions satisfies in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with many columns I want to delete rows with null values in column 'Course' if another column 'Sheet' value is Gdg

```
Course    Sheet_Name
Nan        Gdg
course 1   Gdg
course 2   ret
nan        ret
```

resulting column should be

```
Course   Sheet_Name
course 1   Gdg
course 2   ret
nan        ret
```

This is the code I am using

```
USS_2023 = USS_2023.drop(USS_2023[(USS_2023['Courses'] == np.nan) & [USS_2023['Sheet_Name']=='Gdg']].index)
```

This is the error I am getting

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) function:

```
df.drop(df[df.Course.isna() & df.Sheet_Name.eq('Gdg')].index, inplace=True)
```

---

```
     Course Sheet_Name
1  course 1        Gdg
2  course 2        ret
3       NaN        ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
USS_2023[~(USS_2023['Sheet_Name'].eq('Gdg') & USS_2023['Course'].isna())]
```